# How to center a sidebar menu elements

Tags: html, css, center, sidebar

I found this code example of a responsive sidebar menu in this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sidebar_responsive).

This example is excellent because is totally responsive but
the menu bar elements (Home, News, Contact, About) are always positioned in left part of the menu, i am looking for to position these elements at the top-center in big screen of the page, just like this example

[image] but i was not able to succeed, i am a beginner in css, so i ask for help here, any help is appreciated, thank you very much, here is the code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
.sidebar a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

div.content {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  height: 1000px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .sidebar a {float: left;}
  div.content {margin-left: 0;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .sidebar a {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="sidebar">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h2>Responsive Sidebar Example</h2>
  <p>This example use media queries to transform the sidebar to a top navigation bar when the screen size is 700px or less.</p>
  <p>We have also added a media query for screens that are 400px or less, which will vertically stack and center the navigation links.</p>
  <h3>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</h3>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to change the html "sidebar" div, Add another div "a-holder"

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="a-holder">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

then in the css, add a-holder with parameters like these:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .sidebar a {float: left;}
  div.content {margin-left: 0;}
  .a-holder {
    margin: auto;
    align-self: center;
    width: 80%;
  }
}
```

Then the full code will be

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
.sidebar a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

div.content {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  height: 1000px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .sidebar a {float: left;}
  div.content {margin-left: 0;}
  .a-holder {
    margin: auto;
    align-self: center;
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .sidebar a {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="a-holder">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h2>Responsive Sidebar Example</h2>
  <p>This example use media queries to transform the sidebar to a top navigation bar when the screen size is 700px or less.</p>
  <p>We have also added a media query for screens that are 400px or less, which will vertically stack and center the navigation links.</p>
  <h3>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</h3>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i use this option and it works, in only had to change inside .a-holder { width:50%}, thank you very much for help

Comment: I gave the width 80% because 50% width causes the .a-holder to divide in two rows when  width is very low. anyways, if it works for you.

Comment: if i put 80% to width it does not move to center, only move to the right, what is this? a kind of margin?

Comment: the line align-self: center is not necessary, margin: auto does all the work. so yeah.

Answer (score 1):

As of the image provided in the question and the link provided to the template. I believe you have to add an image at the top of side navigations. As of solution to the link provided in the question.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 767) {
    .sidebar{
    text-align:center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  }
  .sidebar a {
        display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply swap the properties of sidebar from `@media screen and (max-width: 700px)` to regular one

Here is a sample

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
  *{box-sizing: border-box;}
  .sidebar::after {content: ''; clear: both; display: table;}
  .sidebar .logo {float: left; width: 120px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar .social_links{float: right; width: 100px;}
  .sidebar .social_links ul li{list-style:none; display: inline-block;}
  .sidebar .social_links ul{margin: 0;}
  .sidebar .social_links ul li a {padding: 15px 5px}
  .sidebar .menu {float: left; width: calc(100% - 220px); text-align:center;}

.sidebar a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
.sidebar a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

div.content {
  padding: 1px 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .sidebar {
      width: 200px;
      position: fixed;
      height: 100%;
  }
    .sidebar a {float: none;}
  .sidebar .logo {float: none; display: block; width: 100%; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 20px;}
  .sidebar .menu, .sidebar .social_links {float: none; width: 100%;}
  .sidebar .menu a{display: block; }
  .sidebar .social_links li {float: none; text-align:center;}
  .sidebar .social_links ul{padding-left: 0; width: 100%; text-align:center;}
  div.content {margin-left: 0; height: 1000px; margin-left: 200px;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .sidebar a {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="logo">LOGO HERE</div>
  <div class="menu">
   <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
  <div class="social_links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">fb</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">in</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h2>Responsive Sidebar Example</h2>
  <p>This example use media queries to transform the sidebar to a top navigation bar when the screen size is 700px or less.</p>
  <p>We have also added a media query for screens that are 400px or less, which will vertically stack and center the navigation links.</p>
  <h3>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</h3>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This code is also responsive when screen size shrinks below `700px`

PS: Run the code in full page to see how it looks like in desktop view

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
.sidebar a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

div.content {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  height: 1000px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .sidebar a {float: left;}
  div.content {margin-left: 0;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .sidebar a {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h2>Responsive Sidebar Example</h2>
  <p>This example use media queries to transform the sidebar to a top navigation bar when the screen size is 700px or less.</p>
  <p>We have also added a media query for screens that are 400px or less, which will vertically stack and center the navigation links.</p>
  <h3>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</h3>
</div>
```